# How to simulate external TCP traffic in Windows?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, tcp, portforwarding

> I don't have any code yet, so please feel free to move this to a sister site, if you think it belongs there :)

I have a Program A ( I don't have it's source code, so I can't modify it's behavior ) running on my machine which keeps listening to a particular port on the system for TCP data. It's a Peer to Peer application.

```
System 1 running A ====================== System 2 sunning A
```

The program A is supposed to run on systems where I may not be allowed to modify Firewall settings to allow incoming connections on the port the program listens to. I have an EC2 linux server running Ubuntu 16.

So I thought I can use an existing tool or create a program that would connect to the server on port X, and fetch the data from the server, and locally throw that data to the port `A` is listening to.

```
System 1 running A ========= SERVER =========== System 2 sunning A
```

What kind of configuration should I have on the server ? And is there any program I can use for this, or an idea of how to make one ?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to bypass firewalls and hotspots.

Check this out https://github.com/yarrick/iodine, with a proper configuration your would be able to send\receive packets as DNS queries which is I know is always allowed, I used my server to get usual internet access with any hotspot I found.
You would lose some time, higher latency but you will have access.

Hope I helped.